I get this error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Operand type clash: int is incompatible with image
When I want to take a product image from the program and save it in the database, this happened
I try to save an image in byte array after that save in database,
but imagebyteArray returns (int).
I checked all the code line by line and everything was fine and there were no errors, but when saving the photo in the database, the variable that I had defined as byte returns the value (int) and the photo is presented as does not convert bytes.
Here is my code:
Byte[] imagebyteArray;

// forimage
Image temp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
temp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

imagebyteArray = ms.ToArray();

Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.Add("@id", id);
ht.Add("@Name", Textpname.Text);
ht.Add("@price", textprice.Text);
ht.Add("@cat", Convert.ToInt32(coCategory.SelectedValue));
ht.Add("@img", imagebyteArray);
        

This opens the dialog:
private void btnBrows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        ofd.Filter = "image(.jpg, .png)|*.png;*jpg";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FilePath = ofd.FileName;
            PictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(FilePath);
        }
    }
}

And here is the code storing the image in SQL Server:
string qry = "";

if (id == 0)//وارد کردن
{
    qry = "insert into Product values(@Name, @price, @img, @cat)";
}
else//بروز کردن
{
     qry = "Update Product set pName = @Name, pPrice = @price, CategoryID = @cat, pImage = @img where PID = @id";
}

For updating a product already stored in the database:
private void ForUpdateLoade()
{
     string qry = @"select * from Product where PID = @id";

     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, Mainclass.con))
     {
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         da.Fill(dt);

         if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
         {
             Textpname.Text = dt.Rows[0]["pName"].ToString();
             textprice.Text = dt.Rows[0]["pPrice"].ToString();

             Byte[] imageArray = (byte[])(dt.Rows[0]["pImage"]);
             byte[] imagebyteArray = imageArray;
             pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imageArray));
         }
     }
 }


Try setting the position of the memory stream to zero after writing.  You are probably at the end of the stream.  ms.Position = 0;  What is the length of imagebyteArray.

Why are you still using the image data type? It was deprecated almost 20 years ago.

Specify the target columns on your INSERT
qry = "insert into Product values(@Name, @price, @img, @cat)";

should be
qry = "insert into Product(pName,pPrice,pImage,CategoryID) values(@Name, @price, @img, @cat)";

